# Is there a concept called the cross derivative between two functions?

Tags: analysis, derivatives, terminology

Let $f$ and $g$ be two real functions.

Is there already a concept for the quantity $\lim_{h \to 0} \frac{f(x+h)-g(x)}{h}$?

Note that when $g=f$, the quantity, if exists, is the derivative of $f$ at $x$.

Thanks.

Comment: I assume you meant that if $g = f$ then it's the standard derivative.

Comment: Also, the expression you wrote is the derivative at any $x$, not $x = 0$.

Comment: Usually when people say cross-derivative, they mean $\frac{df}{dxdy}$.

Answer (score 5):

If $f $ is continuous, the limit will only exist at those points where  $g (x)=f (x) $, and it will be $f'(x) $. So it's hard for me to see when this notion could be useful/meaningful.